# BST nth smallest (C)

Tags: c, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

This function tries to find the nth smallest number in a BST. I understand it's essentially just an in order traversal with a counter. If that's the case, then why isn't this code working?

Assuming my BST is correctly implemented (which it is), why does it print out 9? It should print out 6.

```
int bst_ith_smallest(BST_PTR t, int i)
{
    if(i > count)
        fprintf(stderr, "Input is greater than BST size");

    return (smallest_helper(t->root, i));
}


int smallest_helper(NODE *r, int i)
{
    if(r==NULL) 
        return;

    smallest_helper(r->left, --i);

    if(i == 0)
        return r->val;

    smallest_helper(r->right, --i);
}


My test function:

int main()
{
  int i;

  int a[] = {8, 2, 7, 9, 11, 3, 2, 6};


  BST_PTR t = bst_create();

  for(i=0; i<8; i++)
    bst_insert(t, a[i]);

  printf("%d\n", bst_ith_smallest(t, 3)); <------ HERE the function is called
  //other tests here
}
```

Comment: As @Rup said. You probably want `--i` instead of `i--`.

Comment: I'm sorry yes, I did do that in my code.. forgot to update it. That wasn't the problem.

Comment: Sorry, had a crisis of confidence and deleted my comment. The problem is that when you recurse down and decrement `i` then you lose that decrement when you recurse back up - `i` will only ever show you the depth. You could instead pass `i` by reference, or pass the new version of `i` back up when you end a recursion.

Comment: Recursion.  Don't you just love it?

Comment: ... and in fact your return values in smallest_helper won't work either - if you do hit the result you're not passing it back up the chain correctly either. (I think that won't compile as-is - the first return with no arg and a missing return at the end.)

Answer (score 1):

Two problems in your `smallest_helper` code: you should be decrementing your counter only when the node is visited, and you should be propagating the return value. Also, be careful with `return` with no value when the function should be returning one.

Try this:

```
int smallest_helper(NODE *r, int i)
{
    if (r == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    int val;
    val = smallest_helper(r->left, i);
    if (val >= 0) {
        return val;
    }
    if (--i == 0) {
        return r->val;
    }
    val = smallest_helper(r->right, i);
    if (val >= 0) {
        return val;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

That assumes your BST has no negative values, hence a negative value is used to indicate an invalid condition.